# Exists $x_{n}$ such that $f'(x_{n})\rightarrow f'(x)$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $f$ be a differntiable function in $(a,b)$. Prove that for every $x\in (a,b)$, exists a sequence $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ ($x_{n}\ne x$  for every $n$) such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f'(x_{n})=f'(x)$.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Look at secant lines that converge to the tangent line. Use the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: @DavidMitra Why is ist necessary to do it like that? Can't we just say that as $f \in C^{1}(a,b)$, for every $x_n \to x$ we know $f'(x_n) \to f'(x)$ as $f'$ is continous?

Comment: @user159517 I'd assume the problem called for $f$ differentiable only; as otherwise it's trivial, as you point out.

Comment: Yes, I meant differntiable only, edited.

Answer (score 1):

Take $y_n=x+\frac{b-x}{2^n}>x$, obviously $y_n\to x$ as $n\to\infty$. By the definition of derivative and Lagrange MVT: there exists $x_n\in(x,y_n)$ such that
$$f'(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(y_n)-f(x)}{y_n-x}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}f'(x_n).$$